# Have I constructed & used "exoplanetship" correctly? If not, what word could be constructed to address the planetary status of an observed phenomenon?

Tags: word-choice, suffixes

In [this Astronomy SE answer to *Is one transit enough to be confident that we detected an exoplanet*](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/48734/7982) I wrote:

> See the excellent answers there to get a better idea of the great extent to which the authors have build a scientific case for "exoplanetship" without actually calling it an exoplanet.

Britanica Dictionary's Ask the Editor's [Using the Suffix -Ship](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/Using-the-Suffix-Ship) says:

> -Ship is a noun suffix. When you add it to the end of a word, that word becomes a noun. It can be added to a word that is already a noun. When that happens, the noun becomes a different noun.
>
> The noun suffix -ship can change the meaning of a word in several different ways. The three most common new meanings are below.
>
> - the position, status, or duties of something
> - skill or ability as someone or something

**update:** I did also do the research mentioned by @EdwinAshworth and found no results so didn't see the need to state it, but now doing so as requested.

I'm using it to achieve the first result, building a case for the status of the observed object to be elevated from unknown to that of an exoplanet.

But I'm not sure if I've done this correctly, so I'd like to ask:

**Question:** Have I constructed and used "exoplanetship" correctly? If not, what word could be constructed to address the planetary status of an observed phenomenon?

Comment: Adding affixes isn't totally productive. You can't expect a novel construction to be an acceptable word. And ELU deals with established usages, not DIY candidate words not found in any dictionary. Whether it is 'acceptable' in creative writing depends on how the public react, but until a dictionary picks up the usage (and this needs researching), it's off-topic here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I did do the research and (unsurprisingly) found absolutely nothing for "exoplanetship" and therefore didn't see any need to add null results to the post. That's easily fixed and has been. I didn't realize that asking how to form new words was off-topic, can you mention where that's stated explicitly for future reference? I'd like to see how that consensus came about. As an aside, it's better for this community to *not provide guidance* to people in the process of potentially creating new words? Is that also a consensus?

Comment: Null results are extremely important. And expected to be posted (with sources attributed)  on ELU.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth and they have now been posted so the need for the close vote to block others from answering is now unclear to me. Also any progress on finding the documented consensus that forming new words was off-topic?

Comment: From my databanked comments: 'As Mitch says on Meta, 'The community has explicitly noted that they should mostly avoid things like neologisms or changes to grammar rules that are proposed to be better (by some criteria), and therefore is not (in general – there are infrequent exceptions to everything) creative. The SE (not just ELU) principles of having mostly answerable non-discussion questions directs us away from making up things or discussing the viability of a change in some rule (these are much too opinion-based and / or broad: two close reasons).' [punctuation tweaked]

Comment: See discussions on ELU.Meta: [Are uncommon neologisms without a {reliable} source acceptable as an answer?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5350/are-uncommon-neologisms-without-a-notable-source-acceptable-as-an-answer)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I have not asked for a neologism as an answer. I've asked about forming words using noun suffixes. And that question has one answer from 2014 with only a score of +2, hardly a community consensus.

Comment: That's disingenuous. You've asked about whether 'exoplanetship' follows the rules for word construction. ELU deals with standard usage; using common morphological word-building methods doesn't guarantee that a DIY candidate be a word. Finding it in a reputable dictionary is almost always the acid test.

Comment: Also, from respected contributor nohat: '... I get pretty anxious when I see questions like [the one then in question], where there is (to my knowledge) no real answer, and then people take this as an invitation to start coining words.
I really don't feel comfortable at all with our site becoming a place where people go who want a word invented. While I delight in exciting new words being invented and promulgated, I think we will rapidly lose our reputation as a place where people can get authoritative answers if many answers are not authoritative, merely inventive.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth again where has that been established by community consensus? And I'm really not disingenuous. You can disagree with me but you should not get personal in comments. I can't say that I'm necessarily an ingenuous question asker but I do ask questions in good faith. I'd like to know if I've used English correctly here or not. No need to assign nefarious intent.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "where there is (to my knowledge) no real answer" I will never understand the thinking behind "If I can't answer it, nobody can". Have more faith in, or at least deference to the larger community. Why not allay the "pretty anxious(ness)" by just holding off and waiting to see what answers are posted rather than advocate for answers to be blocked?

Comment: You have asked 'Have I constructed & used "exoplanetship" correctly?' I'm saying it's not a recognised word, not in the lexis, so the question is off-topic. 'Correct' word formation isn't just about applying rules that often work, it's about whether the result is in the lexicon or not. And checking in various dictionaries is the first place to look. //// 'I think you've used it correctly' really isn't good for the site's reputation.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I understand that you've said that  I've asked for evidence that this is understood to make it off-topic in a demonstrable way. I don't see it in [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and the linked meta question from 2014 with one answer with low score is not convincing me it's a recognized reason for this to be off-topic. In most SE sites what is on or off-topic is *documented* and that documentation comes from community consensus. It's not something that's just made up on the spot. Is ELU different in that regard?

Comment: If the concern is what's "good for the site's reputation" then surely being rules-based rather than *ad hoc* would be a good thing, no? One wouldn't want this site to be viewed as the "wild west" of Stack Exchange.

Comment: @uhoh, to preclude unproductive criticisms, it may be a good idea to emhpasise within the question what you already said in the comments: the question is about the use of the suffix *-ship* (which is well within the scope of this site), and not a request to endorse an arbitrarily coined neologism (which wouldn't be). The question could also be improved by making it explicit why you have doubts about using the suffix in this way; otherwise one may be tempted to respond with just 'yeah, why not'.

Comment: But 'what word could be constructed ...?' cannot be reconciled with site recommendations.

Comment: Related: [-ship vs. -hood](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6454/), [How suffixes like -ness and -ship are chosen when forming abstract nouns?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161272/).

Comment: Sad... answer prevention.

Answer (score 2):

Suffixes *-ness, -hood*, and *-ship* have essentially the same dictionary definitions, so considered in the abstract *Xness, Xhood* and *Xship* all mean the same: the quality of being X. Over time, however, for many values of X, one of the three suffixes became the standard one to use for the quality of being X: we thus say *closeness* (but not *closehood* or *closeship*), *sisterhood* (but not *sisterness* and only rarely *sistership*), and *friendship* (but not *friendness* or *friendhood*). Scrutinising such examples, however, does not reveal any deep principle that determined which suffix became established with which word; it seems to be a result of various unsystematic accidents of history. There is thus no definite ground for saying that it would be incorrect to attach any one of these suffixes to a word with which none of them is already established.

Suffix *-ship*, however, has one minor disadvantage in that it has the same form as the unrelated noun *ship*, which sometimes appears in compounds such as *battleship*. Everybody, of course, knows that a battleship is a ship designed for battles, rather than the quality of being a battle, but when ones sees *Xship*, and it is not an already established term, there could possibly be an ambiguity as to whether it stands for the quality of being X, or for some kind of a ship that has something to do with X. If one encountered *exoplanetship* outside a disambiguating context, one could think that it stands for some kind of a spaceship for travelling to exoplanets. That may be a consideration in deciding whether to use the term, although not a decisive one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've used it correctly, but in my opinion, it's a little ugly. It would look cleaner as

> ... a scientific case for [its] status as an exoplanet, without actually calling it that.